# How to get the callback of onload event for Orbit Slider of Foundation Zurb Framework

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I need to resize the orbit div(the container in which orbit content resides)according to size of the current image. Currently it seems that it is taking the size of the largest image.

Is it possible to get something on the lines of a onload event for orbit slider in Foundation 4.

I could get a handle using the after-slide-change event and do the resizing for all images except the first image(of course it because the slide change is fired when the image changes from 1 to 2).

```
$("#image-gallery-modal").bind('orbit:after-slide-change.fndtn.orbit', function(event){         
  var height = event.target.children[event.data[0].slide_number].children[0].children[0].clientHeight;

  var containerWidth = $("#imgGal").parent().width();
  var childrenCount  = $("#imgGal").children().length;
  var bulletContainerWidth = 14*childrenCount;

  var leftOffest = (containerWidth - bulletContainerWidth)/2;

  $('.orbit-bullets').css('margin-left',leftOffest+'px');
  $("#imgGal").parent().css('height',height+'px');                  
});
```

`image-gallery-modal` is my `div` which contains orbit container, bullets and close button.

I got this idea from orbit.js. There is a line of code

```
.on('orbit:after-slide-change.fndtn.orbit', function(e, orbit) {
  var $slide_number = $container.find('.' + self.settings.slide_number_class);

  if ($slide_number.length === 1) {
    $slide_number.replaceWith(self._slide_number_html(orbit.slide_number, orbit.total_slides));
  }
})
```

Is there some way I can trigger an event onload of the orbit or something on those lines.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: I do not think that its possible to make it work on the fiddle because fiddle does not support Foundation framework..

Comment: http://www.reelax.in/indexv2. There in the section titled IN THEATERS NOW you can see the camera icon. Thats the link for the image gallery. You will notice the problem that I mentioned in the question appearing when you image gallery loads.

Comment: Im sorry, i don't know fundation framework. I won't can help you on this one

Comment: You can absolutely use foundation on jsfiddle or code pen. just load an external asset